# Enum's mapping value is incorrect when using function 'create'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Currently I'm working on a project using Rails as a Framework, it has a problem stemming from another writer's code in the process of initializing objects and saving them to the database with a combination of enum function. That writer's code looks like this:

```
   notification = Notification.personal.create!(
    {
      user:         target,
      template:     template,
      title:        template_language.title_pattern % opts,
      content:      template_language.content_pattern % opts,
      click_action: template.click_action.to_s % opts
    }
  )
```

Notification.rb

```
class Notification < ApplicationRecord
include Partition

 belongs_to :template
 belongs_to :user, optional: true

 delegate :notification_category, to: :template, allow_nil: true

 has_many :notification_reads, dependent: :destroy
 has_many :users, through: :notification_reads

 validates :user_id, presence: true, if: :personal?
 validates :user_id, absence: true, if: :general?

 delegate :notify_partition, to: :user, allow_nil: true
 alias_attribute :partition_name, :notify_partition
 enum category: {
  general: 0,
  personal: 1
 }

  scope :personal_for_user, ->(user_id) { personal.where(user_id: user_id) }
  scope :for_user, ->(user_id) { general.or(personal_for_user(user_id)) }

  scope :read_personal_notifications, lambda { |user_id, is_read = true|
       personal_for_user(user_id).where(is_read: is_read)
  }

  after_create :increase_total_unread

  def be_read_by_user?(reader_id = nil)
    return is_read if personal? && user_id == reader_id

    if general?
      NotificationRead.reset_table_name
      return notification_reads.by_user(reader_id).exists?
    end

    false
   end

   def read_by(reader_id)
     if general?
     notification_reads.build(user_id: reader_id)
     elsif personal?
     user_id == reader_id && self.is_read = true
      self
     end
   end

     private

     def increase_total_unread
      if general?
       User.available.update_all('total_unread = total_unread + 1')
       elsif personal?
        user.increment!(:total_unread)
       end
      end
     end
```

There is an issue that has occurred: although the code written by that person is Notification.personal, there is an occasional problem where some records with a category value of 0 are being stored in the database.

I have also researched some sources, and I learned that the 'create' function immediately saves the object to the database. Therefore, there are potential issues with undefined errors when there is branching in the processing, which does not happen when using new + save.

I am not certain whether the usage of enums by the author is correct when combined with the 'create' function or if it is due to validation functions in the object causing these mysterious errors.

I am a Java programmer who recently transitioned to a Ruby project, so I have some difficulty reading and understanding Ruby library source code. I hope someone can help me. I would greatly appreciate it.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Hi, Just wishing to know, Is there specific reason why you moved from Java to Ruby?

Comment: _"does not happen when using new + save"_ – `create` is literally `new` + `save`, see the implementation at [`active_record/persistence.rb`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v7.1.3/activerecord/lib/active_record/persistence.rb#L37-L38). Your problem must be something else.

Comment: Neither does the problem have anything to with "enum functions" which is not an actual thing.

Comment: @Rajagopalan - My company uses both Java and Ruby, but because there aren't enough Ruby programmers, I also take on the role of Ruby programmer.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way that `Notification.personal.create!( hash: without, category: :general )` can create a notification with category set to `0`. Either that record is being created by some other call, or it's being updated after it was created.